# Is AppEngine standard envinoment only for spiky traffic?

Tags: google-app-engine

We're building an application using Google App Engine. From what I've seen there are 2 types of environments, Standard and Flexible, with huge differences. The problem is I can't seem to find any usage for the Standard environment apart from the faster instance creation compared to the Flexible environment and its ability to scale to 0 instances.

Assuming that our application will never have extreme traffic spikes but more like sinusoidal changes and will always have traffic (will never have to scale down to 0 instances) is there *any* reason to choose the Standard environment over Flexible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from traffic spikes, there are a few other reasons to consider standard:

1) Some services are not available/haven't been implemented yet on Flexible (like memcache)
2) The documentation for flexible is currently lacking.  Most of what you can find on the web right now will be for standard.
3) Integration with android studio.  You can deploy and test your app completely within android studio.  However, this is not necessarily that big of a deal - once you get to know your way around the gcloud console you can do some pretty amazing things.  Changes to your code are applied almost instantly without re-compiling anything.  Just use "gradle jettyRun".  Also, while running locally you can test against live app engine resources like the datastore in whatever project you choose (it could be a test project or even your live production project).

Comment: This is not an Android project but a web project. However with IntelliJ you can test indeed test on a local flexible dev server so no problem there. The documentation issue is something I'm not really sure about I'll have to check it out. Now regarding the extra services, that *might* be an issue although I'm guessing they will be implemented soon. It seems to me that google is pushing more and more for flexible environments instead of standard ones.

Comment: Android Studio can be used for web projects and flexible app engine back ends.  Here is an example of what I mean by "documentation is lacking".  The documentation exists, but the code is such a small example of what you can actually do.  Compare it to the standard app engine cloud datastore documentation and you'll see the difference.  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/using-cloud-datastore

Answer (score 0):

I think one clear advantage of using the standard environment is the free usage. You will get about 28h per day of free usage for the standard enviroment but you do not have any free usage for the flexible environment. You will always have to pay when you are using the flexible instance.

here you will find an overview of standard enviroment free usage limits

https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/always-free-usage-limits

Comment: Indeed that is true and for testing/betaing the application this is actually important. However we will have enough traffic to force billing from day one of release so this advantage will become obsolete. I'd prefer to pay 25$ for one month of Flexible environment usage and build my application without the Standard environment restrictions than having to migrate it soon after release to support Flexible Environment.